# Metrics reporter doesn't report some metrics

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise

Based on metrics-reporter-config-sample.yaml, some of metrics are not exported by either CSVreporter or ConsoleReporter, 
in particular:
org.apache.cassandra.metrics.DroppedMessage.+
org.apache.cassandra.metrics.ReadRepair.+
org.apache.cassandra.metrics.ColumnFamily.system.+
// or any other keyspace metrics

Observed with cassandra versions DSE 5.x and DDC-3.7.

However, the keyspace metrics can be found in e.g.: JCONSOLE.

(I've built and installed newer metrics reported JAR (reporter-config3-3.0.2.jar) but the same outcome)

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out by myself, the patterns are different to the ones listed in sample config file.
So, keyspace and table metrics are:
`org.apache.cassandra.metrics.keyspace.+
org.apache.cassandra.metrics.Table.+`

metrics-reporter-config-sample.yaml needs to be updated to the new cassandra versions

The trick was to export all metrics by changing white-list to black-list:

    `predicate:
      color: "black"
      patterns:
      - ".*JMXONLY$"`
and then figure out the right patterns for white-list.